# Python Pandas remove duplicate Code not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove duplicate columns values in my dataframe.

My code is as below

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Base File.xlsx');

mapping_df = xls.parse('Mapping');
engagement_data_df = xls.parse('Detail Report');
engagement_data_df =engagement_data_df.loc[:,~engagement_data_df.columns.duplicated()]
```

I have 2 duplicate columns called 'BCS Attached Flag'. I tried to deduplicate the columns with the above code but no luck. Can I ask what I am doing wrong?

Adrian

Edit: It seems that the duplicate column appends an attached .1 behind but in the csv file both the columns BCS Attached Flags are there . I did a print(engagement_data_df.head(10))

```
Division Region BCS Attached Flag BCSAttached Flag.1 
China   China A Y                  Y    
Singapore Singapore B Y            Y
```

Comment: What's wrong with `drop_duplicates()`? Edit: Oh, the column names are duplicated!

Comment: Hi that works for unique row not columns

Comment: What do you get now?

Comment: What is `print(engagement_data_df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Because your code working nice, so problem is in data.

Comment: @jezrael [That's what I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924486/python-pandas-remove-duplicate-code-not-working#comment80796210_46924542), but it seems people like downvoting.

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe somebody has bad day :( But not reason for it :(

Comment: Or do you need remove both duplicates columns? Then need `~engagement_data_df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)`

Comment: @AdrianLeeXinhan I deleted my answer. Please fix your question by adding the details I asked for or else this problem cannot be resolved.

Comment: Hi ok. I have fixed my details by placing in the Head(10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first extract text only and then call `duplicated`:

```
m = ~engagement_data_df.columns.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False).duplicated()
engagement_data_df = engagement_data_df.loc[:, m]
```

Comment: HI all, I managed to solve it in a different way. basically i realise as this is an ETL and I am only need Division Region, I did an order of my columns (engagement_data_df = engagement_data_df[order_columns_df];) and capped the column headers which I need. Hence, the remainder column headers are useless and then i removed them. A long way but it worked.

Comment: Yes, it is another solution. But in your question you asj about deduplicate columns and I think my answer do it ;)